# How to create 2 dbsets with the same type in Entity Framework code first?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I created 2 classes which represent entities for a database.

First entity:

```
public enum FlightStatus
{
        checkIn,
        gateClosed,
        arrived,
        departedAt,
        unknown,
        canceled,
        expectedAt,
        delayed,
        InFlight
}

public class Flight 
{
        [Key]
        public string FlightNumber { get; set; }
        public DateTime Arrival { get; set; }
        public DateTime Departure { get; set; }
        public string CityOfArrival { get; set; }
        public string CityOfDeparture { get; set; }
        public char Terminal { get; set; }

        public FlightStatus Status { get; set; }
        public int Gate { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Passanger> PassengerList { get; set; }
        public double PriceForFirstClass { get; set; }
        public double PriceForBusiness { get; set; }
        public double PriceForEconom { get; set; }
}
```

Second entity:

```
public enum Sex
{
        M,
        F
}

public enum FlightClass
{
        First,
        Business,
        Econom,
}

public enum TicketType
{
        OneWay,
        TwoWay,
}

public class Passenger
{
        [Key]
        public string Passport { get; set; }
        public string flightNumber { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("flightNumber")]
        public virtual Flight flight { get; set; }      

        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string SecondName { get; set; }
        public string Nationality { get; set; }       
        public DateTime DateOfbirthday { get; set; }
        public Sex SexOfPassanger { get; set; }
        public FlightClass ClassForPassanger { get; set; }
        public TicketType TypeOfTicket { get; set; }
}
```

Then I created a `DbContext`:

```
class FlightsDatabase : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Flight> Flights { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Flight> FlightsArchive { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Passenger> Passengers { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to use this code:

```
using (FlightsDatabase flights = new FlightsDatabase())
{
    foreach (Flight flight in flights.Flights)
    {
        if (Math.Abs((flight.Departure - DateTime.Now).Days) <= 1)
        {
            timeCame(flight, null);
        }

        if (flight.Departure < DateTime.Now)
        {
            flightsToClean.Add(flight);
        }
    }

    moveOldFlights(flightsToClean, null);
}
```

I get this error

> Multiple object sets per type are not supported. The object sets 'Flights' and 'FlightsArchive' can both contain instances of type 'Project_Airline_Info.Models.Flight'.

So my question is how to create 2 DBsets with same generic type,in DbContext class.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't do this. Consider this line of code:

```
var flight = context.Set<Flight>().Where(f => f.FlightNumber == "123");
```

How does it know which set to use to get the data?

Probably the simplest workaround would be to inherit the `Flight` class and use that for your other `DbSet`:

```
public class ArchiveFlight : Flight
{
}
```

And your context:

```
public class FlightsDatabase :DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Flight> Flights { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ArchiveFlight> FlightsArchive { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Passanger> Passengers { get; set; }
}
```

The bonus of doing this is that you can now add properties to your archived flights, such as the date it was archived:

```
public class ArchiveFlight : Flight
{
    public DateTime DateArchived { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I did something like this but when I reviewed the logs EF was generating two queries to the db when querying only one of the DbSet that have a base class in common. Do you know why?

Comment: No idea, I'd have to see your code/config to even guess.

Answer (score 3):

> So my question is how to create 2 `DbSet`s with same generic type, in `DbContext` class.

You have to use a base class that is not used as a `DbSet` and inherit from that in the classes you will use as a `DbSet`.

If you use an inherited class - e.g. `FlightBase` in the below example - in a `DbSet`, tables for `Flight` and `ArchiveFlight` will not be generated.

**Classes**

```
public class FlightBase
{
    // code
}

public class Flight : FlightBase { }

public class ArchiveFlight : FlightBase { }
```

**DbContext**

```
public class FlightsDatabase : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Flight> Flights { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ArchiveFlight> ArchiveFlights { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Passanger> Passengers { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: How is this different from my answer that has been there for 4 years now?

Comment: Hi @DavidG, it's in the answer. "If you use an inherited class - e.g. FlightBase in the below example - in a DbSet, tables for Flight and ArchiveFlight will not be generated." Maybe it's only true for Entity Framework Core?

Answer (score 0):

You can have 2 dbsets with 2 database like this :

```
private EntityContainer Context = new EntityContainer() { };
private EntityContainer ContextArchive = new EntityContainer("ArchiveEntityContainer") { };

//add this second constructor in your Context.tt file
public <#=code.Escape(container)#>(string connectionString) : base(connectionString) { };
//to have it in your autogenerated Context.cs file
public EntityContainer(string connectionString) : base(connectionString) { };
```

Of course, you can use **using** statement. You'll have to detach objects from *Context*  in order to insert it to *ContextArchive* and reciprocally